# AMPL IPOPT gives wrong optimal solution while solve result is "solved"

Tags: optimization, ampl, ipopt

I am trying to solve a very simple optimization problem in AMPL with IPOPT as follow:

```
var x1 >= 0 ;
minimize obj: -(x1^2)+x1;
```

obviously the problem is unbounded. but IPOPT gives me:

```
******************************************************************************
This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.
Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).
     For more information visit http://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt
******************************************************************************

This is Ipopt version 3.12.4, running with linear solver mumps.
NOTE: Other linear solvers might be more efficient (see Ipopt documentation).

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:        0
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        0
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:        1

Total number of variables............................:        1
                 variables with only lower bounds:        1
            variables with lower and upper bounds:        0
                 variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:        0
Total number of inequality constraints...............:        0
    inequality constraints with only lower bounds:        0
inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
    inequality constraints with only upper bounds:        0

iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
0  9.8999902e-03 0.00e+00 2.00e-02  -1.0 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 0.00e+00   0
1  1.5346023e-04 0.00e+00 1.50e-09  -3.8 9.85e-03    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
2  1.7888952e-06 0.00e+00 1.84e-11  -5.7 1.52e-04    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
3 -7.5005506e-09 0.00e+00 2.51e-14  -8.6 1.80e-06    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1

Number of Iterations....: 3

                               (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:  -7.5005505996934397e-09   -7.5005505996934397e-09
Dual infeasibility......:   2.5091040356528538e-14    2.5091040356528538e-14
Constraint violation....:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Complementarity.........:   2.4994494940593761e-09    2.4994494940593761e-09
Overall NLP error.......:   2.4994494940593761e-09    2.4994494940593761e-09


Number of objective function evaluations             = 4
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 4
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 0
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 0
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 0
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 0
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 3
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =      0.001
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =      0.000

EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.

Ipopt 3.12.4: Optimal Solution Found

suffix ipopt_zU_out OUT;
suffix ipopt_zL_out OUT;
ampl: display x1;
x1 = 0
```

when I change the solver to Gurobi, it gives this message:

```
 Gurobi 6.5.0: unbounded; variable.unbdd returned.
```

which is what I expected.
I can not understand why it happens and now I don't know if I need to check it for all the problem that I am trying to solve to not converging to the the wrong optimal solution. As it is a super simple example it is a little bit strange.

I would appreciate if anybody can help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Zero is somewhat of a bad starting point. Use e.g. `var x1 >= 0 := 1;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already identified the basic problem, but elaborating a little on why these two solvers give different results:

IPOPT is designed to cover a wide range of optimisation problems, so it uses some fairly general numeric optimisation methods. I'm not familiar with the details of IPOPT but usually this sort of approach relies on picking a starting point, looking at the curvature of the objective function in the neighbourhood of that starting point, and following the curvature "downhill" until they find a local optimum. Different starting points can lead to different results. In this case IPOPT is probably defaulting to zero for the starting point, so it's right on top of that local minimum. As Erwin's suggested, if you specify a different starting point it might find the unboundedness.

Gurobi is designed specifically for quadratic/linear problems, so it uses very different methods which aren't susceptible to local-minimum issues, and it will probably be much more efficient for quadratics. But it doesn't support more general objective functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand why it happened. the objective function

```
 -(x1^2)+x1;
```

is not convex. therefore the given solution is local optimum.